# Adding microdata using Structured Data Markup Helper HTML

Tags: tinymce, html, visual-editor

I am trying to add schema microdata to a [wordpress website](http://www.aladdincarpetcleaning.com.au). I have tried to insert some microdata directly in the wp editor (text mode) but every time i save the page it does not save the code.

I tried a few plugins but when I check with the structured testing tool it doesn't seem like they are working.

I generated the microdata using [this tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper), but I am not able to edit the html. Can I do it via cpanel? I cannot find how i can edit the html under the cpanel.

How can I add the generated data to the home page?

Comment: May you please provide an example of a "_schema microdata_"?

Answer (score 0):

By default TinyMCE, the (visual) editor of WordPress, strips [schema microdata](https://schema.org/) from input. There are plugins ([example](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/protect-schemaorg-markup-in-html-editor/)) that will prevent this behaviour. Or you can do it yourself by adding this snippet to your `functions.php` ([docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements)):

```
function wpse238918_allow_schema ($in) {
    if(!empty($in['extended_valid_elements']))
        $in['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',';
    $in['extended_valid_elements'] .= '@[id|class|style|title|itemscope|itemtype|itemprop|datetime|rel],div,dl,ul,dt,dd,li,span,a|rev|charset|href|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur]';
    return $in;
    }
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse238918_allow_schema' );
```

Comment: @DesislavaAngelova Great that worked. Please accept this answer (check to the left), so this question does not appear as 'unsolved' in the system later on.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without any code injections is using a wordpress plugin to configure Classic editor to accept all metadata specific content.

Plugin is called: Advanced TinyMCE Configuration

Its configuration is:  @[itemscope|itemtype|itemid|itemprop|content],div,span,h1,h2,h2,h4,h5,h6time[datetime]

More info here: https://bghints.blogspot.com/2023/03/stop-wordpress-from-removing-microdata.html